# How can I change the size of the plot markers

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I use `ListPlot` in order to plot four sets of data and also insert legends in my plot. Here is the Mathematica code

```
data1 = {{0, 48}, {50, 59}, {100, 69}, {150, 78}, {200, 86}, {250, 
87}, {300, 88}, {350, 88.5}, {400, 89}, {450, 89.5}, {500, 90}};
data2 = {{0, 50}, {21, 57}, {45, 65}, {69, 73}, {100, 82}, {150, 
86}, {200, 90}, {250, 90.5}, {300, 91}, {350, 92}, {400, 
93}, {450, 93.5}, {500, 94}};
data3 = {{0, 55}, {50, 60}, {100, 65}, {150, 72}, {200, 80}, {250, 
84}, {300, 87}, {350, 89}, {400, 91}, {450, 91.5}, {500, 92}};
data4 = {{0, 63}, {50, 66}, {100, 69}, {150, 72}, {200, 74.5}, {250, 
77}, {300, 79}, {350, 81}, {400, 83}, {450, 85}, {500, 87}};

col = {Blue, Darker[Green], Red, Magenta};
leg = {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(z\)]\) = 5", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(z\)]\) = 20", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(z\)]\) = 40", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(z\)]\) = 60"};
plrange = {45, 100};

P0 = ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, Frame -> True, 
PlotStyle -> Table[{Thickness[0.003], col[[i]]}, {i, 1, 4}], 
Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}, 
FrameLabel -> {Subscript["M", "n"], 
"Percentage of chaotic orbits (%)"}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
PlotRange -> plrange, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
PlotLegends -> 
LineLegend[leg, LegendMarkers -> Automatic, 
LegendMarkerSize -> {{20, 25}}, 
LabelStyle -> 
 Directive[FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]]]
```

which produces the following output using version 9

[image]

My main issue is how to increase the size of the plot markers in the legend. Inside the main plot, I can control the size of the markers by `PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}`. On the other hand, even though I tried a lot, I cannot do the same regarding the markers in the legend. Any ideas?

---

**Update 2015-07-22:**  In versions 10.x, the above input does create legend markers that are the same size as in the plot itself.  But if we specify [custom plot makers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10), we will quickly discover that the legend markers will be inconsistently sized.

```
ListPlot[
 Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 2}],
 PlotMarkers -> {
   Graphics[{Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 7], 
   Graphics[{Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 13]
 },
 Joined -> True,
 PlotLegends -> {"line1", "line2"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the fundamental issue remains.

Comment: You can try defining your own `LegendMarkers`.

Comment: You mean of course inside the `PlotLegends`. How could I do this? Any clue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You also aren't getting the right line thickness in your legend. I'd suggest a slightly different route, of creating custom legend markers, similar to the method described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21359/8), and including them in a `SwatchLegend`.

```
legmarkers =  MapThread[Graphics[{#1, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
     Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], #2}] &, {col, {Disk[{0, 0}, 0.3], 
    Rectangle[{-0.3, -0.3}, {0.3, 0.3}], 
    GeometricTransformation[
     Polygon[{{-0.3, -0.3}, {0.3, -0.3}, {0.3, 0.3}, {-0.3, 0.3}}], 
     RotationTransform[45 Degree]], 
    Polygon[0.3 ({{1, -Sqrt[3.]/2}, {0, 
         Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, -Sqrt[3.]/2}})]} }]
```

[image]

You can then specify the markers as shown. Notice that I had to tweak the `LegendMarkerSize` option to get the aspect ratio of the graphics correct.

```
P0 = ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Table[{Thickness[0.003], col[[i]]}, {i, 1, 4}], 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}, 
  FrameLabel -> {Subscript["M", "n"], 
    "Percentage of chaotic orbits (%)"}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  PlotRange -> plrange, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   SwatchLegend[leg, LegendMarkers -> legmarkers , 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 12}}, 
    LabelStyle -> 
     Directive[FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In 10.x, the simplest thing is to specify the `PlotMarkers` directly, but as noted, the legends ignore `ImageSize` if specified within the graphic. The correct way to do this is to use the

```
{{g1, s1}, {g2, s2} ...}
```

form of `PlotMarkers`, e.g.

```
ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 2}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[{Disk[]}], 1/4}, {Graphics[{Rectangle[]}], 1/8}}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"line1", "line2"}]
```

[image]

The reason is the legend is not otherwise passed any sizing info, e.g.

```
In[25]:= Options[g[[2,1]], LegendMarkers]

Out[25]= {LegendMarkers -> 
 {{Graphics[{Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 7],Automatic}, 
  {Graphics[{Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 13], Automatic}}}
```

where `g` is your version, and note, I swapped `GraphicsBox` for `Graphics` for readability. As these are essentially put together using `Inset`, the graphic is assumed to take the entire picture, and then it is scaled down to size. But, the scaling is now set to `Automatic`.

Comment: Thank you!  A few questions:  **1** Do you know why the legend injects `EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3], Black]]` in the `Graphics` expression of the marker?  The plot only injects the colour, but not `EdgeForm`.  I need to put a manual `EdgeForm` to get rid of this. **2** "I swapped `GraphicsBox` for `Graphics` for readability" <- What are you referring to?  I didn't see `GraphicsBox`.  **3** Is there a way to specify marker sizes in absolute units and still synchronize the legend and the legend with the plot? `ImageSize` was absolute, this way seems relative to the plot size.

Comment: @Szabolcs **1** I think to improve readability. :) **2** copying the legend markers introduce the box form, I suspect. So, the statement is likely erroneous. **3** According to the `PlotMarkers` doc, its a relative size. I do not understand why it is not the same for the text form markers, e.g. `"\[FilledCircle]"`. It's even an [example](http://wolfram.com/xid/09bqceu00-viio06).

Comment: The problem with relative sizes is that I often need to prepare figures to size, e.g. `cm = 72/2.54; ListPlot[..., ImageSize -> 9 cm]`.  This will give me a result that is precisely 9 cm wide when exported to PDF (well, if I also use legends, I need to set the printing style environment to "screen" to preserve dimensions during `Export` ...).  Since here the plot marker sizes are relative, using `ImageSize` will again destroy the correspondence between the legend and the plot ...

Comment: Preparing figures to size is often better than resizing them after exporting, because I can specify the font sizes in points to match the main text.   Resized figures usually end up having random font sizes ...

Comment: I see. That is problematic. Let me poke around and see.

Answer (score 9):

For version 10.x the answer can be found [in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendMarkers.html):

```
ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 2}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 20}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 10}}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"line1", "line2"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This should work for graphics objects like the OP used too.

Comment: This works even without explicit plot marker sizes, but this uses plot markers that are font glyphs, with all the problems that brings, such as incorrect centering.  In your example all the circles are lower than they should be, relative to the line.  That's why I used `Graphics`-based plot markers.  But then the size is suddenly relative to the image size, so specifying the `ImageSize` option destroys the correspondence between the plot and the legend.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that and it was one reason to share a picture because I find it ugly as hell. Additionally, you see the *plot markers cover everying* issue that you found out yourself. Unpolished feature.

Comment: and what about "-" , "+", "*" how to change size of this kind of markers?