# Background of PlotMarkers

Tags: plotting, bugs

I use the StandardReport style sheet in my notebooks, but I would like to export plots without any backgrounds. Apparently, there isn't a global option to change the background on a plot, so I change the background for everything:

```
bgc = White;
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}
, Background -> bgc
, TicksStyle -> {{12, Background -> bgc}, {12, Background -> bgc}}
, Joined -> True
, PlotMarkers -> Automatic
]
```

But there is still a gray background on plot markers.

[image: example]

How can I disable it?

Comment: Could you provide a specific example for your plot? I have gray background of markers with `PlotMarkers -> Automatic` and transparent background with `PlotMarkers -> None`. It works for me (Linux, V10.0.1) but contradicts the docs, which say `None` = no markers.

Comment: PlotMarkers -> None gives me no makers at all (Linux, V9.0.0.0)

Comment: Try with `PlotMarkers -> {}`

Comment: Almost :) But how can I tune the marker size?

Comment: There is no background on the `PlotMarkers` on my plot (Mac OSX, v. 10.0.0).

Comment: V9.0.0.0 is the first v9 release so is very buggy, you should ugrade.

Comment: Rather than close this as off-topic would it not be better to rewrite it as a bug report and tag it as such?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit, 28.06.2016**

There is a Background on PlotMarkers on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014) **with** the StandardReport style:

```
 bgc = White;
 ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, Background -> bgc, 
 TicksStyle -> {{12, Background -> bgc}, {12, Background -> bgc}}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

[image]

There is **no** Background on PlotMarkers on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014) **with** the StandardReport style when using `BaseStyle -> {Background -> None}`:

```
bgc = White;
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}
 , Background -> bgc
 , TicksStyle -> {{12, Background -> bgc}, {12, Background -> bgc}}
 , Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[{Disk[]}], 1/4}}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}
 , BaseStyle -> {Background -> None}]
```

[image]

[image]

There is no Background on PlotMarkers on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014) **without** the StandardReport style.

```
bgc = White;
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, Background -> bgc, 
TicksStyle -> {{12, Background -> bgc}, {12, Background -> bgc}}, 
Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

And the the marker size can be tuned like so (see [How can I change the size of the plot markers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-the-plot-markers)):

```
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}
, Joined -> True
, PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[{Disk[]}], 1/4}}
, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually there is, with the StandardReport style.  It appears to be the same problem I asked about a few days ago: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118830/background-colour-of-text-in-graphics  Plot markers are text too.