# Background colour of text in graphics

Tags: graphics, formatting

I see this strange behaviour when both the containing cells and the graphics have a non-white background.  I set the style of a notebook to "Standard Report" (Format -> Stylesheet) and did this:

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Text["Hello, world!"]}, Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

I see this in each of the following versions: 9.0.1, 10.0.2, 10.3.1, 10.4.1 on OS X 10.11.5 and 10.3.1 and 10.4.1 on Windows 10.

Can others reproduce the problem?

Is there a simple fix for the frame ticks that doesn't require specifying tick labels explicitly?

Comment: Same behaviour on Windows 10. `FrameTicksStyle -> Background -> None` fixes the frame ticks for me.

Comment: @Simon Can you post an answer?  It is not obvious that that is a valid option ... I actually did try `FrameTicksStyle -> {Background -> None}`, which didn't work.

Comment: I think a list is interpreted as being a list of styles for different sides of the frame, and a length 1 list is not valid.

Comment: @Simon `Directive` works, but I found it strange to see options in a `Directive` (although I think I've seen it before...)

Comment: I am not seeing the problem with V10.4.1 running on OS X 10.10.2

Comment: I don't see this problem either. MMA 10.0.1.0, OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: @m_goldberg Ah, so it's stylesheet dependent then!  Do you remember which stylesheet you used?

Comment: It is very much stylesheet dependent. As far I can tell, Standard Report is the only style which exhibits this problem. Try converting your test notebook to any other style and see if you don't find that it is only Standard Report that is guilty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same behaviour is observed in Mathematica 10.4.1 under Windows 10. A fix for the frame ticks is to use the option `FrameTicksStyle -> Background -> None`

[image]